# CSS, Adding additional background on hover

Tags: css, background, hover

Is there any way to add an additional background to a div on hover? For example to add a black background with 50% opacity on top of an already existing background image.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do that *without* hover?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post some code what you're trying to achieve, i posted a simple example.
If it helps you use also `!important` to force the overriding

```
div{
    background: yellow;
}
div:hover {
    background:black;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using multiple backgrounds. The overlay would be a gradient that you can hide with `background-size`. When hovered, you can set the `background-size` to `auto`, and the overlay would be displayed.

```css
.bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(https://picsum.photos/300/200);
  background-size: 0, auto;
}
.bg:hover {
  background-size: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```